# How to create image from dockerfile without starting the container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-run

I have a dockerfile that is suppsed to start the tomcat. I want to create **and not run the image** from that dockerfile so that in docker images I can see the image. docker run -it logs me in to container but I dont want to create container and log in to it.

I just want to create a image from dockerfile (without creating a container of it).

By which command can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the `build` command.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: @im_baby-:: Will this create a image which I can see in "docker images" command ?

Comment: Read the docs. They will answer all your questions

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION 1:** Just run  `docker build -t my-new-image .` 
 This command will tag image with name you provide.

**SOLUTION 2:** command `docker build .` will create `<none>` image (check `docker images` output  image will be created with image ID ). You can tag this image manually with any image name by command:
`docker tag <IMAGE-ID> my-image-name`

Answer (score 0):

Run `docker build -t <yourImageName> -f <yourDockerfileName> .` Or just simply `docker build .`

Don't forget to add the  "dot" at the end. It specifies where to find the files for the “context” of the build.

Comment: @czende-:: docker build -t myimage -f . gives the error "docker build require exactly 1 argument" and "docker build . " command is building the image successfully but in "docker images" command I am not able to see the image

Comment: The `-f` option isn't needed if the file is named exactly `Dockerfile` and is in the `.` directory.